# Unable to run existing java Play Framework project on windows machine

Tags: java, windows, playframework, playframework-2.4

I'm getting

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Users\stepa\workspace\sse-chat-java\\activator-launch-1.1.0.jar
```

when running [Markus Jura's **Play Framework** simple chat application](https://github.com/markusjura/sse-chat-java) on windows 10 system.

On a Ubuntu machine [Markus Jura's **Play Framework** simple chat application](https://github.com/markusjura/sse-chat-java) works without any problems.

This is what I tried so far:

- reinstalling [Typesafe Activator](https://www.typesafe.com/activator/download) to the currently newest version (2.4.3 - same as on Ubuntu machine)
- searching for *activator-launch-1.1.0.jar* (not present on any of the machines)
- searching for someone with same problem

I'm running out of ideas. I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 places where you may try to change version. See image below (but please also check another file).

I'm not sure it will fully fix your issue, but it worth a try.

[image]